# Mariadb replication slave broken

Tags: mysql, mariadb, master-slave-replication

I run Mariadb 10.3 on a Debian 10.3 server. The database was standalone until now and worked fine. Now I want to set it up as a replication slave. I use this as a guide:
https://www.linuxbabe.com/mariadb/master-slave-replication-ubuntu-18-04-18-10

I added these lines into /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf:

```
server-id              = 02
relay-log-index        = /var/log/mysql/slave-relay-bin.index
relay-log              = /var/log/mysql/slave-relay-bin
replicate-do-db        = <my database>
```

and set up the change master setting. At this point I realized that this did not have any effect, and I discovered that the line to include the entries in mariadb.conf.d was missing in /etc/mysql/my.cnf. I added this line and restarted the mariadb service. Now things started to get weird. The service failed to start, and in the error.log I find these lines:

```
2020-05-03 13:59:31 7 [Note] Reading Master_info: 'master-master01.info'  Relay_info:'relay-log-master01.info'
2020-05-03 13:59:31 7 [ERROR] Failed to open the relay log './mysqld-relay-bin-master01.000009' (relay_log_pos 4)
2020-05-03 13:59:31 7 [ERROR] Could not find target log during relay log initialization
2020-05-03 13:59:31 7 [ERROR] Initialized Master_info from 'master-master01.info' failed
2020-05-03 13:59:31 7 [Note] Added new Master_info 'master01' to hash table
2020-05-03 13:59:31 0 [Warning] Reading of some Master_info entries failed
2020-05-03 13:59:31 0 [ERROR] Failed to initialize multi master structures
2020-05-03 13:59:31 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

To get a fresh start, I removed the added lines from 50-server.cnf and restarted the service. Now it starts, but in the error.log I find this:

```
2020-05-03 14:04:41 7 [Note] Reading Master_info: 'master-master01.info'  Relay_info:'relay-log-master01.info'
2020-05-03 14:04:41 7 [Warning] Neither --relay-log nor --relay-log-index were used; so replication may break when this MySQL server acts as a slave and has his hostname changed!! Please use '--log-basename=#' or '--relay-log=mysqld-relay-bin' to avoid this problem.
2020-05-03 14:04:41 7 [Note] Initialized Master_info from 'master-master01.info'
2020-05-03 14:04:41 7 [Note] Added new Master_info 'master01' to hash table
2020-05-03 14:04:41 8 [Note] Master 'master01': Slave I/O thread: Start asynchronous replication to master 'replicant@10.8.0.12:3306' in log 'master-bin.000004' at position 343
2020-05-03 14:04:41 7 [Note] Started replication for 'master01'
2020-05-03 14:04:41 0 [Note] Reading of all Master_info entries succeeded
2020-05-03 14:04:41 0 [Note] Added new Master_info '' to hash table
2020-05-03 14:04:41 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '10.3.22-MariaDB-0+deb10u1'  socket: '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  Debian 10
2020-05-03 14:04:41 9 [Note] Master 'master01': Slave SQL thread initialized, starting replication in log 'master-bin.000004' at position 256, relay log './mysqld-relay-bin-master01.000031' position: 4
```

> show slave status;
>   Empty set (0.001 sec)

So this seems to be an inconsistent state: I cannot start the service with correct relay-bin files, but when I remove them, the replication starts anyway and gives these warnings. What can I do to clean this up?

Replication seems to work, btw.

Comment: recommend avoiding replicate-do-db  and other replication filters (there's a caveat in the documentation).  Default is to replicate everything. Did you just remove `relay-log*` variables or was server-id removed too (`server-id` is needed and numbers don't have leading `0`). Its possible you started replication `START SLAVE` while the relay-log-files where in their default values.

Comment: I do need the replication filters. I want only one database to replicate, and two tables of that database not to replicate. I omitted the other replicate-ignore-table entries as I thought this would not be important for this problem.